SwiftUI with FirebaseFirestore
I've googled a lot but haven't found an answer yet. I'm a beginner who just started programming SwiftUI with Xcode. This is a very simple example. I tested with Xcode 15.4, Firebase 11.1.0, ISO 17.5 simulator and iPhone 15 Pro Max. Note that fetching data from the database is working.

WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR I0000 00:00:1724935720.773638  111338 config.cc:230] gRPC experiments enabled: call_status_override_on_cancellation, http2_stats_fix, monitoring_experiment, pick_first_new, trace_record_callops, work_serializer_clears_time_cache nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke [C1] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection TCP Conn 0x6000033050e0 Failed : error 0:50 [50] I0000 00:00:1724935720.853425  111359 subchannel.cc:806] subchannel 0x104919e10 {address=ipv6:%5B2404:6800:4006:814::200a%5D:443, args={grpc.client_channel_factory=0x600000049cc0, grpc.default_authority=firestore.googleapis.com, grpc.http2_scheme=https, grpc.internal.channel_credentials=0x60000260d020, grpc.internal.client_channel_call_destination=0x102cd4fb8, grpc.internal.event_engine=0x600000008ef0, grpc.internal.security_connector=0x600002c01400, grpc.internal.subchannel_pool=0x6000029442a0, grpc.keepalive_time_ms=30000, grpc.primary_user_agent=grpc-c++/1.65.1, grpc.resource_quota=0x600000cbfe40, grpc.server_uri=dns:///firestore.googleapis.com}}: connect failed (UNKNOWN:(domain:NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code:50, description:The operation couldn’t be completed. Network is down) {file:"/var/folders/hn/5bx1f4_d4ds5vhwhkxc7vdcr0000gn/T/ZipRelease/2024-07-25T04-01-28/project-ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/transport/error_utils.cc", file_line:150, created_time:"2024-08-30T00:48:40.853037+12:00", grpc_status:2}), backing off for 955 ms

Error Code
I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Please help.
The part below is the source code.
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct BizKoreaNZApp: App {
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var users = [User]()
    @State private var isLoading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Start")
        NavigationView {
            List(users) { user in
                Text(user.name)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Users")
            .onAppear {
                fetchUsers()
            }
            .overlay(isLoading ? ProgressView() : nil)
        }
    }
    func fetchUsers() {
        isLoading = true
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            isLoading = false
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching users: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let snapshot = snapshot {
                self.users = snapshot.documents.map { document in
                    let data = document.data()
                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    return User(name: name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct User: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}


Have you tried using the recommended import, as described at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

I have tried all imports but I am still getting the network down message and data is being fetched successfully from the database.

That error says network is down at the bottom

I've done a lot of testing with networking. I've successfully connected to firestore.googleapis.com via Safari on my emulator (iPhone 15 Pro Max), but I'm getting an error in Xcode that it can't connect. The syntax for the error is db.collection, and I'm getting the error message even if I just connect without retrieving any data. Also, the error doesn't always occur. Very occasionally, the error doesn't appear. I guess it's because the connection is successful.

@DanielLee Were you able to resolve this ? Getting the same issue while using firebase firestore in Swift UI project

I haven't solved the problem yet, but I'm guessing it's an ipv6 network issue.

I am facing similar issue

Started a new project and getting the same (or very similar error). Doesn't seem to be stopping me reading and writing though.
